# TypeScript: type "XXX" is not assignable to type "XXX|YYY"

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm writing a higher-order function, `opposite(fn)`. This `opposite` takes a boolean or numeric `fn` function as input, and returns a new function, *which should be of the same type as* `fn`. If the original function is of boolean-returning type, the new function returns "not that boolean". If the original function is of number-returning type, the new function returns 1 or 0 depending if the result was zero or not. You can use `opposite` to invert a filter, from `someArray.filter(testCondition)` to `someArray.filter(opposite(testCondition))`.

**The problem**: both `return` sentences produce an error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<T>' ts(2322)`.

**Why cannot I assign a `boolean` or `number` to a `boolean|number`? How should I apply data types to my `opposite` function?**

```
const opposite =

  < T extends
      | ((...args: any[]) => boolean)
      | ((...args: any[]) => number)
  >(fn: T) =>

  (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {

    const result = fn(...args);
    if (typeof result === "number") {
      return result === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
      return !result;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trip up on things like this every time I pick up TS again.

I don't think you can type this without partially turning off type checking one way or another.

Note that I have added the util `Widen` because your function signature was wrong: if `fn` is `() => true as const`, then `opposite(fn)` is `() => true` instead of `() => boolean`

```js
type Widen<T> = T extends number ? number : T extends boolean ? boolean : T;

const opposite =

  < T extends
      | ((...args: any[]) => boolean)
      | ((...args: any[]) => number)
  >(fn: T) =>

  (...args: Parameters<T>): Widen<ReturnType<T>> => {

    const result = fn(...args);
    if (typeof result === "number") {
      return result === 0 ? 1 : 0 as any;
    //                            ------
    } else {
      return !result as any;
    //               ------
    }
  };
```

```js
const opposite:{
    <Args extends unknown[]>(f: (...args: Args) => boolean): (...args: Args) => boolean
    <Args extends unknown[]>(f: (...args: Args) => number): (...args: Args) => 0 | 1
} = <Args extends unknown[]>(f: (...args: Args) => boolean | number) => (...args: Args): any => {
//                                                                                       ---
    const result = f(...args);

    if(typeof result === 'number') {
        return result === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
        return !result;
    }
};
```

```js
type Widen<T> = T extends number ? number : T extends boolean ? boolean : T;

const opposite =
    <Args extends unknown[], R extends boolean | number>
        (f: (...args: Args) => R) => (...args: Args): Widen<R> => {
            const result = f(...args);

            if(typeof result === 'number') {
                return result === 0 ? 1 : 0 as any;
                //                          ------ 
            } else {
                return !result as any;
                //             ------
            }
        };
```

A few things can conspire for it not to compile:

- In your case I think the culprit is that `ReturnType<T>` is undetermined: it is not `number | boolean` and the compiler won't compute the value.
- In the case of the implementation with overloads, the problem is that overloads are an intersection, and the intersection `boolean & number` is `never`.
- The problem with the last implementation is that `R` could be provided by the caller: If they pass in `5`, `boolean` no longer extends `R`.

I may be slightly wrong about those interpretations but this mental model works quite well and the bottom line is you are stuck.

Comment: Based on the answer by Geoffrey, I pared down and fixed my code. I didn't feel well about the `Widen<T>` construct; essentially it says "if T returns a number, then a number; else, if T returns a boolean, a boolean; and otherwise, whatever T returns" -- for me, that felt just like saying "whatever T returns".

We can do without `Widen`; the real key was the changes that Geoffrey highlighted, going from `return ... as number` to `return ... as any`. That's interesting; instead of us telling TypeScript what the type of the answer is, we have to let it figure that out by itself!

Comment: Be careful, using `any` does not enable TS to infer anything: `any` extends any type and any type extends `any`, so using it basically turns off type checking. In this case the return type and the type constraints are useful to callers, but the implementation is not type checked so as the implementer you must be careful to fulfill your contract

Comment: as for `Widen`, have a look at this playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCAO8QQJZQKYwLwCgcxgB4YAVGdADwzABMJ8DGAfGAClYDouBDAJwHMIALhjcwATwDaAXQCU2AHwwARiBAAbdGNkNGMFuy4c+gkWKlzFMMAFcAtsvS8dBBawBmYESXlYFeAk4eAWEYAAU+bjt0DF4IQhIFWREAJRibXjAScXh0BKU-GABvAMZQSFhedAgbdVgsGE8g4xDZAG5dGBR3Nigc9BAeqpq67CwGgCJbBycJ+RK9AiqoDLAYYdr68ZgABhgAfhgARhgRPe4IUQkOvQBfcnUITAXF5dWYAEIN0Yur8RvGLcGLcOjhytAuhAAILqADu3HEEBIvBsmAarF8SigKMwv3BUA6AHpCZCYfDEcjUSIMVZsai8PjSXCERAAGLcR5ouCIZBodCsFDQ5kUnE6YlM8lsjlPamYmB09BAA You can't return `ReturnType<T>` because the return type can be too narrow

Comment: About the way `Widen` is written: `T extends number ? number : ...` means "if `T` is `5`, return `number` instead of `5`". `opposite(() => 5)` should not be of type `() => 5` but `() => number` or `() => 0` if you want to be more precise